# Make Icon change position to mouse click spot in Open Layers 6

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

How do you make it so wherever you click on the map, the Icon added on the map just instantly teleports to those coordinates? Currently in the official Open Layers 6 ['Examples' page](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-icon.html), it shows the drag and drop example with the following example:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import TileJSON from 'ol/source/TileJSON';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Icon, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {Modify} from 'ol/interaction';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';

const iconFeature = new Feature({
  geometry: new Point([0, 0]),
  name: 'Null Island',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500,
});

const iconStyle = new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    src: 'data/icon.png',
  }),
});

iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: [iconFeature],
});

const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
});

const rasterLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new TileJSON({
    url: 'https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/aj.1x1-degrees.json?secure=1',
    crossOrigin: '',
  }),
});

const target = document.getElementById('map');
const map = new Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: target,
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3,
  }),
});

const modify = new Modify({
  hitDetection: vectorLayer,
  source: vectorSource,
});
modify.on(['modifystart', 'modifyend'], function (evt) {
  target.style.cursor = evt.type === 'modifystart' ? 'grabbing' : 'pointer';
});
const overlaySource = modify.getOverlay().getSource();
overlaySource.on(['addfeature', 'removefeature'], function (evt) {
  target.style.cursor = evt.type === 'addfeature' ? 'pointer' : '';
});

map.addInteraction(modify);
```

Their wiki does not mention about any convenient property like `Icon.setPosition`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a click listener to the map and change the geometry of the feature:

```js
map.on('click', function (event) {
  iconFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(event.coordinate);
});
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much. The draggable feature however does not work for me. :)